# Exporting JS IIFE library to React Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, import, export

I'm just starting to learn React JS. So I have this 2 JS files:

1. Polyfill.js -> github
2. CustomNavbar.js -> mine

polyfill.js structure

```
export default (function(window){
...
var classy = {
   ...
}
...
})(window);

!window.addEventListener && window.Element && (function () {
...
---code---
...
})();
```

this is customnavbar.js

```
import { cs } from "./polyfill";

(function(){
...
function openNav(){
   ...
   cs.classy.add(overlay, 'on-overlay');
   ...
}
...
})();
```

this is my component.jsx

```
import "./customnavbar.js"
...
...
```

it didn't work, the error said that cs is not defined. Maybe I did wrong with the export syntax?

```
<script src="./polyfill.js">
<script src="./customnavbar.js">
```

^ i want it to work just like pure HTML, but I don't know how to do it in react. please help!

Comment: What value is returned from the IIFE?

Comment: What's `cs` and what did you expect it to be there?

Comment: cs is supposed to be the polyfills.js so i can get the var classy, but it seems like the cs is null. so I thought that I might be wrong on the export syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import "./customnavbar.js"`

is not valid syntax for module imports.

Set `type` of `<script>` element to `"module"`

```
<script src="./polyfill.js" type="module">
```

`return` the `classy` object from the IIFE

"script.js"

```
export default (() => { const classy = {fn() { return 1 }}; return classy })();
```

`import` the exported `classy object

"polyfill.js"

```
import classy from "./script.js";
// do stuff
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0orq8Bvk6nOT8tX0qLg?p=preview